# android media player delay

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am making a game for android which needs to play a small beep whenever a user touches a certain object.

To do this I have this simple code to create the media player. beep is a small `.ogg` file of ~1.5 sec length.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.beep);
mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

and use it like this

```
mp.start();
```

The problem I am having is that my game uses the android canvas, and the thread which draws to the canvas also calls `mp.start()`. I have discovered that playing the sound is taking quite a lot of time, and it is very varied in how long it takes. Sometimes 1ms, sometimes 15ms. This appears to be causing my game to noticeably lag a little bit, as the android canvas is pretty slow anyway.

I've had a look at the logs and I don't appear to having garbage collection causing the delay. I'm wondering if anyone can give me some advice to reduce this delay

EDIT - I've just discovered that `MediaPlayer` is designed for longer sound files, and `SoundPool` is better for shorter audio files. However, I load the file into the `mediaPlayer` only once, so I don't see how it should make any difference. I will test it out though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for my english

Use SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer cause MediaPlayer need releasing memory after each call or call method `mp.release()` after each call of player

[SoundPool tutorial here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html#sound)